# Is it possible to enable or disable the specific JMX Metrics to monitor for a Kafka cluster using Jconsole

Tags: apache-kafka, jmx

On my Kafka cluster,I am able to view and monitor certain Mbean JMX metrics like RequestsPerSec etc. However I only see a very few of the metrics mentioned in the Apache Kafka documentation on my JConsole. Is there a way to enable others. Especially is there a way to enable a few specific ones explicitly.

Comment: What are the metrics you can't find? Are they the broker metrics?

Answer (score 1):

Kafka has different metric sets on particular components, and some versions of Kafka have more/less metrics than others

The brokers, producers and consumers each have different JMX metrics

There's no way to disable/enable MBeans